# cmake error with catkin_make, ROS installation

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have created a workspace as catkin_ws. Then, `catkin_make` was run successful. 
   After I type `catkin_create_pkg ros_basics_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp` and then the all folders and files created  in  ros_basics_tutorials folder.

However After this command, I type `cd catkin_ws`

and then   `catkin_make`

Below error is shown Cmake Error, Could NOT find cpp (missing: cpp_DIR), cmake_check_build_system' failed

```
Base path: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/selcuk/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/selcuk/python/anaconda2/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/selcuk/catkin_ws/build/test_results
CMake Error: Target gtest has dependency information when it shouldn't.
Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry
  gtest_LIB_DEPENDS
from the cache.
CMake Error: Target gtest_main has dependency information when it shouldn't.
Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry
  gtest_main_LIB_DEPENDS
from the cache.
CMake Error: Target gmock has dependency information when it shouldn't.
Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry
  gmock_LIB_DEPENDS
from the cache.
CMake Error: Target gmock_main has dependency information when it shouldn't.
Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry
  gmock_main_LIB_DEPENDS
from the cache.
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - ros_basics_tutorials
-- ~~  - naoqi_driver
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ros_basics_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_basics_tutorials)
-- Could NOT find cpp (missing: cpp_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'cpp'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cpp" with any of
  the following names:

    cppConfig.cmake
    cpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "cpp_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cpp" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros_basics_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/selcuk/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/selcuk/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I couldn't solve? How can solve it?

Comment: `Your cache is probably stale.` - Follow this warning and remove the `CMakeCache.txt` file from the build directory.

Comment: İt solve Cmake errors  but I need to install cpp package to solve Could NOT find cpp (missing: cpp_DIR), cmake_check_build_system' failed.

Comment: post CMakeLists.txt  Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to anathor project folder which i canceled under the catkin_ws.  I deleted it and complied again. The error solved.